# Loading effect using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making an effort to implement a loading using hooks on react.
I can do it using componentDidMount, but this applications uses Hoocks.
I create the state and the changestate, but i can not set and use it on my html.
Here is my code:

First of all i made a get request whit axios and async/await

```
const fetchContent = async content => {
    const data = []

    for await (const item of content) {
            const info = await axios.get(
                `url/id`
            )
                data.push({ componentDisplay: item.title });
       }
    return data
}
```

then i call it whit usseEffect

```
const ContentGroups = ({ content , ads}) => {
    const [contentResult, setResult] = useState([])

    const [contentLoading, changeCondition] = useState(true)

    const change = () => {
       changeCondition(false) 
   }

    useEffect(
        () => {
            fetchContent(content).then(data =>  setResult(data)
            change() 
        },
        [content]
    )
    return (

        <React.Fragment>
            { contentLoading ? <Loading /> : <Conteiner> } // always show me the container, although contentLoading innitial state is true..
        </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't think your example compiles, you're missing an open div and a parenthesis

Comment: Daniel, yeah, sorry i remove the </div> anyway it dosen t work...

Comment: Your `useEffect()` is watching for changes in `[content]` which is a variable that doesn't exist. Don't know if that's your problem, but that should be `[contentResult]`, doesn't it?

Comment: Finally i do it by iterating over contentResult:  { !contentResult.length ? <div>loading..</div> : <Content /> thank you very much